# How do you stop objects looking so jaggy in the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

As ringed in orange, my model looks extremely jaggy and clippy in the object mode's viewpoint. This is with viewport shading selected. How can I make the model not look this way?

Please note I've already gone on went on object data properties (green triangle) > Normals > tick-boxed 'Auto Smooth' and dialled it way up, but not much difference really. Any pointers?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Does your look jaggy and messy in the viewport? In 'view' near the top right of your view - which can be toggled on and off by pressing the letter 'n', adjust the Clip Start, to say, 0.01 m.

No more jaggies!

Comment: It could be that it needs adjusted in either direction depending on the scale of the objects in the scene